# Rebase feature branch to avoid merges

Tags: mercurial, rebase

I have default branch which is public and feature branch which is private.

```
default 1-----4-------8
         \     \
feature   2-3---5-6-7
```

When i make updates to default I want them available for feature branch.
I could do it with repeated merges, but then I would end up with many merges.
I don't have problem with editing history; feature branch is only on my local
repository.

I want to do this:

```
default 1-----4-8
         \       \
feature   2-3-----5-6-7
```

or even better:

```
default 1-4-8
             \
feature       2-3-5-6-7
```

I tried to do:

```
hg rebase --dest 8 --source 5
```

But it moved elements to wrong branch.

```
default 1-----4-8-5-6-7
         \       /
feature   2-3----
```

Branches have changes in different files, so no need to worry about complex merges.

**Edit:**

`--keepbranches` option seems to do what I want on the surface. But merge commit information seems strange: it's like MercurialHg thinks that it is still a default branch, but only renamed as feature -branch. It seems kind of hack, and I am not 100% convinced that this is the way to go.

Comment: Since you have already done the merge of 3 and 4 into 5, it will be a bit tedious to sort out again. I don't know of a very easy way to do it. The only way I can think of is to manually re-apply 5, 6, 7 onto 3 and then rebase the whole bunch. This will give you your "even better" situation.

Comment: What is wrong with merges? Every time you graft or re-apply the patch you are effectively doing the merge but not documenting (in a changeset) how that happened.

Comment: @Ringding: Since the changes didn't overlap and having the chages from default earlier on feature branch doesn't matter, I was hoping that it wouldn't be too hard for Mercurial to figure out automatically.

Comment: @Edward: Having too many merges adds unnecessary noise to commit history, especially if they could be combined to fewer merges without losing anything. Mercurial also has a tendency to reorder revisions on clone, which can make graph with many one-way merges look more complex than what it really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your workflow is much better suited to using [Mercurial Queues](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) than it is to using rebase.

The reason being that it is not a trivial thing to change the parent of the branch to be 8 when it used to be 1 but that is exactly the effect that you get when using MQ.

Mercurial queues keeps a set of patches, one for each revision, and makes it easy to apply / unapply as required whilst you get the feature complete.

In your scenario you'd do the following:

1. Create first patch to contain changeset 2.
2. Create second patch to contain changeset 3.
3. Remove all patches
4. Pull changeset 4
5. Apply all patches
6. Create patch for changeset 5
7. Create patch for changeset 6
8. Create patch for changeset 7
9. Remove all patches
10. Pull changeset 8
11. Apply all patches

This would end up in the situation that you want in your even better scenario.

Typically, you wouldn't necessarily create one patch per changeset.  You'd create a patch and keep refreshing it until you were happy with it.

When you're happy that the feature is complete, you'd finialise the patches and push allowing the rest of the team to see the code.

You could look at this [tutorial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqTutorial) to get a start with MQ.